# less :extend() with media queries

Tags: css, less

I am trying to extend a simple class

```
.positionAbsolute {
    position: absolute;
}
```

My issue here is that I can extend it like:

```
#something:extend(.positionAbsolute) {
   something else
}
```

But from inside the media query itself, If i try from outside no rule is extended at all.

Is this the normal behaviour?, why is doing that?, In such case I will have to create like four equal classes to extend in each media query case, is there some workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand it right (it's always hard to guess w/o seeing an exact CSS output you need to achieve), but it looks like you need something like:

```css
.positionAbsolute {
    position: absolute;
}

#something:extend(.positionAbsolute) {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
        something: else;
    }
}
```

The other way around is:

```css
.positionAbsolute {
    position: absolute;
}

#class-1,
#class-2 {
    &:extend(.positionAbsolute);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #class-1 {
        something: else;
    }

    #class-2 {
        something-even: more else;
    }
}
```

That way you will have to repeat selectors instead of media queries.

Comment: tks, could be a solution, but will make me to repeat the media queries for each element.

Comment: > repeat the media queries for each element.
Yep. There's another way around (you can repeat elements sintead of media queries) - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do this, and was quite disappointed I couldn't put the extend within a media query. Fortunately I was able to use a mixin for what I wanted. This may work for some situations. I can't really tell what you're actually doing with your case.

```
.centerVertically()
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    border: 2px solid red;

    .content
    {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

used in media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: @break_tablet)
{
    /* doesn't work
       &:before:extend(.centerVertically_wrapper){}
       .content:extend(.centerVertically_child){}
    */

    .centerVertically();
```

Comment: Just try to imagine how the resulting CSS would look when you extend a top level class with another class inside a media rule and it becomes obvious why [extend inside media rule can only target classes within the same media rule](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-scoping-extend-inside-media).

Comment: this is why we can't have nice things

Comment: "Nice things"? Well, I'd say we can: notice that if your class inside media block has almost the same properties as a top level class has you don't need to duplicate *all* these properties inside that media class definition. Instead you still re-use the shared properties via `extend` at the top level, and within the media definition of the same class you set unique properties only. (Not counting that similar media quiery declaration itself also can be abstractcted into a mixin (or even merged with `extend` in the same mixin), there're a few examples on that here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

The best I came up with I turned into [a GIST here](https://gist.github.com/tappily/c23650dc9ee154005271). Basically, I created an externalized **reference** mixin for the query and imported all the possible contexts into it. LESS sees through the query when you are referencing a class to extend but it will export it.

Reference:

```
.narrow {
 @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
   @import "position";
   @import "z";
 }
}
```

Export:

```
@import (reference) "narrow";

.style-1:extend(.position .abs, .narrow .position .rel) {
}
.style-2:extend(.narrow .position .rel) {
}
.style-3:extend(.narrow .z .index-1) {
}
```